# Two nearly identical Access queries, one gives 'Invalid procedure call'

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

This runs correctly:

```
select [feature number], 
len(mid([feature number],instr([feature number],"."))) > 2 from featuredata
```

This gives an `Invalid procedure call` error:

```
select [feature number] from featuredata 
where len(mid([feature number],instr([feature number],"."))) > 2
```

`feature number` is a Text field, but even when I prevent non-numeric values from being processed:

```
select [feature number] from featuredata 
where iif(isnumeric([feature number]),  
len(mid([feature number],
instr([feature number],"."))) > 2,false)
```

I still get the `Invalid procedure call` error.  Why am I getting this error?

Comment: In an `IIf` both results are evaluated, but only one is returned.  You may need to try using a case statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is this:

If `instr([feature number],".")` is 0, then you call

`mid([feature number], 0)` , and this is invalid.

You shouldn't check for `isnumeric([feature number])` in your `iif`, but for

```
instr([feature number],".") > 0
```

---

**Edit**: Why does the first version run?

While it runs, it should return `#Function!` for every row where there is no "." in `[feature number]`. So the error happens here too.